# Android - PHP - WampServer - Database row cannot update?

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql-update

I have successfully connect my android app with a database (WampServer).
The user can register (register.php) and login (login.php).The rows after registration are in the database.
However, when I try to update a row (in the location.php), everything goes wrong. The database has 6 columns with the names: (username,email,mobile_phone,password,latitude,longtitude). I am trying after the user registers, to take his latitude and longitude and send them to the database and update the 'latitude' and 'longtitude'. Primary key is the username. Moreover, 'latitude' and 'longtitude' are Varchar(50).

```
<?php
//Connect to database
require "init.php";
//Variables
$username = $_POST["username"];
$latitude = $_POST["latitude"];
$longtitude = $_POST["longitude"]; 

//different ways I have tried!
$sql = "UPDATE users SET username='Doe' WHERE username='$username'";
//I even tried to insert it, but still no!
$sql_query = "insert into users values('$username','a','1','1','2','2');";

$sql_query  = "select latitude from users where username like '$username';";
$result_lat = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
$sql_query = "select longtitude from users where username like '$username';";
$result_long = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
?>
```

I have tested that the values that I am sending from the app to location.php are accurate. Therefore the app sends the data, the location.php receives them, but the update is not happening! I have tried many different thing, with no result! Can anyone help me? Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only query for update right now. You need to execute that query by mysqli_query function ;)

Comment: Yeah mysqli_query($con,$sql); is needed!